# Produce Random Numbers in Laravel with Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, random

I'm new in Vue.js and I'm having a hard time producing random numbers.  In my Vue file, I have this piece of code under script:

```
var numeral = require("numeral");
Vue.filter("formatNumber", function(value)
{
    return numeral(value).format("0,0");
});
```

...calling the method:

```
getRandomNum()
    {
        this.like = Math.random() * 100;
        this.rate = Math.random() * 10;
        this.comment = Math.random() * 100;
    }
```

works like a charm that produces the number of likes, ratings and comments in my html:

[image]

However, if you'd notice, even though they're random in a sense whenever I refresh my DOM, technically they're still all the same in each rows. My question is, is there a way that I can produce a whole totally different random numbers in each row? Thanks! Please respect, I'm new to Vue.js.

Comment: By refreshing the DOM, do you mean to refresh the page? Or through some Ajax calls?

Comment: by refreshing the page.

Comment: Well, you're building an SPA, if you simply intend to give the users an ability to refresh the contents, I would add a "refresh" button and do stuff without reloading the whole page.

Comment: That's right. But, going back to the topic, perhaps a more appropriate suggestion?

Comment: Anything that might be of help?

Answer (score 1):

Your reactive data properties are global, meaning they are defined in the global data scope

`data(){
  return {
    likes: 0,
    rate: 0,
    comment: 0
  }
}`

you have to make each of your iterable elements (v-for loop) into a component. and pass the relevant data into it. When it is rendered, it would be done uniquely. For example.

`<div v-for="comment in comments">
  <comment-component :comment="comments"></comment-component>
</div>`

in your `comment-component`

```
<template id="comment-component">
<div id="box">
   <h3>{{comment.title}}</h3>
   <p>{{comment.description</p>
   <div>{{comment.date}} | {{getRandomNumber()}}</div>`
</template>
export default{
 data(){
  return {
    likes: 0,
    rate: 0,
    comment: 0
  }
 },
 methods: {
  getRandomNum()
  {
    this.like = Math.random() * 100;
    this.rate = Math.random() * 10;
    this.comment = Math.random() * 100;
  }
 },
 filters:{

 }
```

Now when your page renders, it treats each item in your collection independently.

Comment: This works. Though to save time, instead of making 1 component for each, I've put them altogether in one component. Also, I did not include {:comment="comments"} (or that manner), will it affect the backend?

Comment: You only needed one component though, your loop would determine how many to render. You would not need the binded prop if you have no need to pass data from parent to child. But your logic looks like you need to pass data between components. Glad you were able to sort it out.